# Reproduce duplicate insertion into Redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to reproduce a scenario that occurred in one of our production servers. We have a lookup table which we populate using the below query. The goal here is to extract all unique account ID from a main table to a lookup table and reference the lookup ID in the main table.

```sql
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO AccountLookup (Account)
    SELECT DISTINCT Account FROM Staging db
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AccountLookup acct WHERE acct.Account = db.Account);
END;
```

The problem is, despite selecting only distinct elements from the staging table and filtering using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, we seem to get few duplicate entries in the `AccountLookup` table.

It is very much possible that two parallel transactions could have caused this inconsistency. But since transactions in Redshift uses Serializable isolation by default, I'm wondering how this could have happened.

To reproduce this locally, I connected to a Redshift cluster from two instances of DBeaver and trying to simulate the scenario. But I either get a `Serializable Isolation Violation` or no duplicate insertions. I never could reproduce this problem.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Also, any suggestions to fix this problem are welcome.

Comment: this looks exactly like my answer in your last question, the answer toyour problem is lock the table, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOCK.html

Comment: @nbk Explicit table locks should definitely fix the problem at the cost of performance. But I believe serializable transactions are pretty pessimistic such that this kind of inconsistencies never happen. I'm just curious about the root cause. Any thoughts?

Comment: i think you are on the right track, the query alone will not produce duplicates, as i wrote n my answer, but if two or more processes try to insert the same data, you must search for a better approach or lock the tables. so you must check if two processes call the transaction., have you mire criteria besides the exist that can minimize the duplicates